# Python SQL query returns "ORA-00936: missing expression" when I replace hard-coded value with variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I have a database full of information and I'm trying to write a python script that will pull some of the data and organize it into a report. Here's what I have so far:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('REDACTED')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Currently hard-coded to return single known motor number
cursor.execute('SELECT MOTORID FROM MOTORS WHERE SERIALNUM=804')
# Returns [(11)]
lMotorID = cursor.fetchall()

# Query Assessments for list of how long the motor had run when assessment was taken
cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT RUNHOURS FROM ASSESSMENTS WHERE MOTORID = %s \
               ORDER BY RUNHOURS" % lMotorID[0])
# Returns [(0), (0.91), (8), (25), ...]
lHours = cursor.fetchall()

# Query for number of installed sensors by senor type
cursor.execute("SELECT SENSTYP, COUNT(STATUS) FROM HEALTH LEFT JOIN INSTRUMENTATION \
               ON HEALTH.INSTROID = INSTRUMENTATION.INSTROID LEFT JOIN ASSESSMENTS \
               ON HEALTH.ASSESSID = ASSESSMENTS.ASSESSID WHERE ASSESSMENTS.ASSESSID \
               IN (SELECT ASSESSID FROM ASSESSMENTS WHERE MOTORID = 11 AND RUNHOURS = %s) \
               GROUP BY SENSTYP ORDER BY SENSTYP" % lHours[2])
# Returns a 2-column dataframe with sensor type in column 0 and the total in column 1
dfTotal = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
```

Because I want this to work for any motor, I want to replace the hard-coded `MOTORID = 11` with a variable. I tried replacing the last query with this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT SENSTYP, COUNT(STATUS) FROM HEALTH LEFT JOIN INSTRUMENTATION \
               ON HEALTH.INSTROID = INSTRUMENTATION.INSTROID LEFT JOIN ASSESSMENTS \
               ON HEALTH.ASSESSID = ASSESSMENTS.ASSESSID WHERE ASSESSMENTS.ASSESSID \
               IN (SELECT ASSESSID FROM ASSESSMENTS WHERE MOTORID = %s AND RUNHOURS = %s) \
               GROUP BY SENSTYP ORDER BY SENSTYP" % (lMotorID[0], lHours[2])) 
dfTotal = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
```

And that's when I get the ORA-00936 error. I don't understand why the query is complete with a hard-coded value, but not when the value is replaced by a variable (one that works in a previous query). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside from the point about using bind variables, try printing your variables, or do a `try catch` and print `Cursor.statement` to see exactly what query is being run. I suspect your `lMotorID[0]` is actually NULL.

Comment: @kfinity Then why does `lMotorID[0]` work in the 2nd query (Begins `# Query Assessments`)?

Comment: Good point, you probably have a different issue. I'd still recommend printing your variables and/or the full query.

Comment: Doing a `try except finally` definitely helped. Adding `print(cursor.statement)` to the `except` block showed me that it was passing tuples rather than the values. Adding `[0]` after each variable got me the actual value and then the query worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to fix the syntax for `cursor.execute` such as

```
cursor.execute('... WHERE MOTORID = :mt_id AND RUNHOURS = :run_hr', mt_id=lMotorID[0][0], run_hr=lHours[2][0])
```

prefixing the parameters by percentage sign is valid for MySQL connections through python, while Oracle accepts colons.

or another option would be using an ordered tuple :

```
cursor.execute('... WHERE MOTORID = :1 AND RUNHOURS = :2', (lMotorID[0][0],lHours[2][0]))
```

Comment: For further reading, see the documentation: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html

Comment: True, never format query inline with %, it can lead at least to SQL injection vulnerability

Comment: I tried both of these options and both times I got "NotSupportedError: Python value of type tuple not supported."

Comment: I tried on python 3.6.5 ad Oracle DB 12.1.0.2, there is no problem with none of the options. Btw, third option might be using brackets to wrap a tuple such as `[ lMotorID[0], lHours[2] ]` @SMPerron